# ArcGIS Online - How to display map data over time interval

Tags: arcgis-online, time

I have NOAA Tornado data from 1955-2015 that I'd like to display on a map over time. I found an [ArcGIS Online Help article](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-time.htm) describing how to enable time settings but it has me confused. It says:

> 1. Verify that you are signed in to your organization and have privileges to create content and publish hosted feature layers.
> 2. Open **My Content** and open the hosted feature layer with temporal data.
> 3. In the **Layers** section of the page, click the small arrow icon next to the layer where you want to enable time and click **Time Settings**.
> 4. Check the box next to **Enable time**.
> 5. Choose to record the time data as **specific events in time** or **time ranges with a start and end time**.
> 6. Choose the time field or fields in your data.

I'm having issues with **Step 3**. When I click the arrow icon next to the layer, there is no option for Time Settings:

[image: no Time Settings option]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you verify that you have at least one date-time formatted field in that layer?

Comment: @MaryBeth - The data has a column labeled "Date" that is formated like "2001-11-23".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enable this on the item details page of the layer.. so in your screenshot click on view item details

then click on time settings here
[image]

Then you have the modal dialog to configure your time settings
[image]

Comment: The Time Settings option isn't there. It goes straight from Export To to Enable Attachments. Does that mean there's something wrong with the data?

Comment: is there time data in the feature layer?

Comment: Yes. There's a column labeled "Date" that contains dates in this format: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Just want to double check that the field labeled date is also of date type and not a string field.

Comment: How can I tell the difference?

Comment: Oh, just found it... The type is esriFieldTypeString. How do I change its data type?

Comment: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008953